# Automated creation of Custom Slack Bots

Tags: automation, bots, slack, chatbot

Is it possible to automate configuration of Slack Custom bots via code? So far I have found only manual UI-based configuration.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtUcl.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not possible. You need to manually configure and setup your Slack app. However, once configured in can be installed by multiple Slack teams.